# Custom events for Telerik Upload Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I was trying to use Telerik Upload control in my project. In that, i need to use custom button. The button is shown when upload control has atleast 1 file. If no file is present then the custom button to be hidden.

Here is my View code : (note: createitems is my button ID)

```
function UploadSuccess(e) {
    $('#createitems').show();

}

function UploadRemove(e) {
    var files = e.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
     $('#createitems').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#createitems').show();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the possibilities for this issue.

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me the possibilities for this issue."* -- Did not understand what it means.

Comment: I need a solution for that query...

Comment: My current code is not working.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide and show your button if file atleast 1

```
function UploadRemove(e) {
    var files = e.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        $('#createitems').show();

    }
    else {
        $('#createitems').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: the button is not hiding when no files in the selected files list.